# Google Cloud error. 404 The requested URL was not found on this server, but it exists

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iis-10

I have created a new instance of vm in google cloud with windows 2016 and IIS 10 where certain requests to files are intercepted by google returning this response:

404. That's an error. (google logo)

The requested URL was not found on this server. That's all we know.

The problem is that the resource does exist, and pressing F5 is accessed intermittently, and other times that error appears.

Can anybody help me. The site is www.deruedas.com.ar

Comment: Just a guess, but it sounds like a problem on the server end. If it's intermittently serving the page and returning 404 the rest of the time, I'd look at the server logs and see what's going on. Does this happen only with one URL, or with everything on that server? (Also, are you using a CDN?)

Comment: Google appears to be having issues on their end. There is another question with the same issue, and all signs indicate it's on Google's end
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956029/sporradic-google-404s-on-my-google-compute-engine-instance