# Sporadic Google 404's on my Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm hosting a website on a GCE instance. I have the DNS for domain.com pointed to a static IP that I have reserved on Google Cloud. This instance runs nginx on port 80, and forwards requests to a node app running on 8080.

It's been running smoothly for months, but today my client has been complaining that they sometimes see 404s. I opened the site in a browser and began refreshing. I'm noticing that all pages and assets that are requested from this domain will randomly respond with a Google 404 page

[image]

I opened both nginx and node access logs and I see the request is not even making it to nginx. It's not a DNS issue, because if I run curl a few times: `curl -I 123.123.123.123` I will still see it respond with a 404 every so often.

Google cloud's status page indicates no outages. What am I missing? Where else can the problem lie?

Comment: How many node apps do you have? I've seen this behaviour when you load-balance but one of the backend apps is down.

Comment: @Hitobat A single node app. I'm not doing any load balancing at any point.

Comment: I am also running into this with a static IP, seems like a widespread issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm also hitting this issue today, running an express app on compute engine with Nginx. It's weird because if it were an actual 404, I would expect express to respond.

I also have intermittent issues making outbound requests, and they'll occasionally timeout. I've tried restarting and re-configuring the entire app. Google's status pages also don't point to any issues.

EDIT: Tried to resolve this by creating a new instance and using a snapshot of the old boot disk... strangely, it seemed to work fine when using the ephemeral IP that was generated, but when I switched it to the static IP I had set up with the original instance, I started hitting the same issue. I also can't set up the machine in a different zone because of where the IP is set up, and I don't want to generate a new one due and then deal with the DNS changes.

Comment: It's definitely an issue on Google's end. I'm getting 404s even when I stop the instance at the IP and try to access it via the IP, which makes no sense.

Comment: @AdrianSmith hmm, weird that they haven't addressed it though. I haven't been able to get in touch with anyone, but definitely really disruptive and still hasn't been resolved for me.

Comment: Changing to a new static IP resolved the issue for me. I was also able to get outbound requests working by creating a forwarding rule with my original static IP, and then assigning the instance an ephemeral IP, which at least got me 50% of the way there until I could get the DNS settings and everything adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, currently google support asked me to change the external ip to fix it, but I can not do it at the moment because it would mean waiting for the DNS dispersion of my domain. If someone can try this option, respond if it results in a solution.

My case:
[Google Cloud error. 404 The requested URL was not found on this server, but it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954316/google-cloud-error-404-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-but-it-e)

Answer (score 0):

I change the ip of my server and that solved the problem, I acquired a premium type ip, not probe with another ip standard.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue on Google's side. Your best bet normally is to open an ticket on the Google [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui).

For this specific issue, there is already a [ticket open](https://issuetracker.google.com/112927328). Feel free to add more comments to the thread and following along for a resolution.