# 404 error in a web page using gcloud deployment?

Tags: html, yaml, web-deployment, gcloud

I followed every steps of the following link trying to deploy a simple helloworld web app(use exact same code as the following link) to google cloud but getting 404 error for my deployed [web link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website#before_you_begin).

here is app.yaml:

[image]

here is index.html:

```html
html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>
      This is a simple static HTML file that will be served from Google App
      Engine.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out why getting 404 error, anything wrong with the app.yaml file?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954316/google-cloud-error-404-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-but-it-e

Comment: Is the `index.html` file in a directory `www` within your project directory?

Comment: Please consider using `python37` rather than Python 2.x as this version of Python is now end-of-life.

Comment: Please don't use images of sources. As you have done with the HTML, embed the app.yaml in your question directly. This saves us having to click links to review, aids copying code and keeps the question standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your use case:

1.this should be the structure of the folder `static`:

[image]

2.after you copied the code for `app.yaml` and `index.html` run the following commands inside `static` folder:

```
 gcloud app deploy
 gcloud app browse
```

3.go to `https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com`

[image]